# Как заставить DialogFragment отображаться при повороте экрана?

Tags: android

Уже второй день воюю с этими диалогами и не могу понять как отображать его при повороте экрана.

```
public class ChoiceDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private static final String REQUEST_TEXT_DIALOG = "request_text_dialog";
    private View view = null;
    private TextView request;
    private Button positiveBtn;
    private Button negativeBtn;
    private String text;

    public static ChoiceDialog newInstance(String textRequest){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(REQUEST_TEXT_DIALOG, textRequest);
        ChoiceDialog dialog = new ChoiceDialog();
        dialog.setArguments(bundle);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
        text = getArguments().getString(REQUEST_TEXT_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
        if (view == null) {
            getDialog().setTitle("saved location is alongside");
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_container, container, false);
            request = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog_id);
            positiveBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.positive_btn_id);
            negativeBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.negative_btn_id);

            positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            negativeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            request.setText(text);
        }
        else{
            ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.positive_btn_id:
                Log.i(TAG, "positive button pressed");
                ...
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.negative_btn_id:
                Log.i(TAG, "negative button pressed");
                ...
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов диалога из `Activity` происходит из `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)`:

```
...
String stringSubtitle = "some text";
choiceDialog = ChoiceDialog.newInstance(stringSubtitle);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(choiceDialog, "choice_dialog")
                           .commit();
```

Не понимаю, почему `setRetainInstance(true)` не выполняет свою задачу (прописывал в `Activity` `choiceDialog.setRetainInstance(true)` - результат тот-же), хотя проверял в `onCreate()` после поворота - фрагмент моего диалога существует!?!

Comment: Отображайте диалог его методом show, не через транзакцию добавления

Comment: добавил через choiceDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "choice_dialog"); результат тот же. Установил прозрачность для слоя активити (думал, может фрагмент диалога перекрывает при повороте мой фрагмент SupportMapFragment из разметки активити), но эффекта нет: диалог после поворота просто не отображается.

Comment: Любители setRetain, так в чем проблема? При повороте чтоб диалог не закрывался и сохранял состояние? Так это по дефолту происходит, просто его нужно правильно создать и показывать. Или проблема в другом?

Comment: А как тогда правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По идее необходимо вызывать `setRetainInstance(true)` и этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы диалог верно отрабатывал повороты, это в теории, в реалиях существует [известный баг](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36929400) из-за которого наблюдается то что наблюдается.

Путь обхода также известен [и уже описан](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657490/how-to-properly-retain-a-dialogfragment-through-rotation):

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    // handles https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17423
    if (dialog != null && getRetainInstance()) {
        dialog.setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

В некоторых случаях это тоже не работает. Тогда можно тупо запрещать поворот при создании диалога:

```
int currentOrientation=activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
activity.setRequestedOrientation(currentOrientation);
```

потом при его закрытии разблокировать возможность поворота:

`activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);`

Comment: отлично, все летает!